# TurnJS and browser zooming

Tags: zooming, turnjs

I've recently stumbled upon the TurnJS plugin to create a page turning effect. I'm working on a project right now with it to recreate a Flash flipbook that was built in the past. One of the stipulations is that it has to be shrunk or magnified to fill the browser window without scrolling. I've been experimenting with my own simple JS utilizing browser transform properties to scale the container. The scaling is working however the flip book effects don't work very well once everything has been scaled (shaky page transitions and the page corners don't work very well).

I've also been experimenting with without much luck either.

I've also implemented a chart on the second page using Flot and have also noticed that when zoomed, the mouse over are not aligned correctly. It's similar to what's happening with the page corners.

The original flash version: http://www.return-it.ca/ar2010/index.html
Without zooming: http://dev.bitpowered.ca/encorp/

Have I gone about this the wrong way? Is there an alternative to getthing this all to work, or am I SOL on this one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have two more links that show my experimentation that I was not able to include above: My zooming: http://dev.bitpowered.ca/encorpzoom/  
ZooMooz zooming: http://dev.bitpowered.ca/encorpzoom2